# how to "dark out" widgets in the background?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to "dark out" all widgets, except a special widget which the user is working with.
This special widget should be on a predefined position. Everything else should be "darked out".

Is there an easy way to acchieve a result like this?

What I did is:
 - put on every element an overlay except one element

The problem is that this overlay is not laying over the whole screen (you see it ends on the top of my picture and I think this solution is not the cleanest as it is very complicated to control:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "darked out" ? Like fading out a widget to make it invisible ?

Comment: by "darked out" do you mean out of focus ?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like modal barrier color, and modal barrier behavior. The easiest way to achieve that is by using [showDialog function](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html).

Comment: Hi Dennis, if I understood your solution right this works with an alert but I should not use alerts for this. I updated my question with a screenshot and an explaination too.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. In this situation I'd be looking at custom-implemented modal barrier widget stacked over the content with four panels covering everything except the widget of interest. It could have a method receiving the reference to the widget that has to remain visible.

Comment: Hi Dennis thanks for this idea, I am working with several collumns and I have no idea how to acchieve this solution.

How can I tell the widget that should be visible to appear above the modal barrier?

Maybe could you make a simple example?
This would be very great...

Comment: My thinking was to create a custom modal barrier layer that replicates positions and sizes of  the elements in the main layout. Then you'd be able to selectively show/hide elements in the in the barrier to block/allow access to the matching elements in the main layer. I don't have a working solution, but this is the first approach that I'd be exploring faced with the same requirements.